# Can I find the line number of a line that matches an expression in ant?

Tags: regex, ant

Basically what I want to do is insert some extra code in to the output files from a 3rd party code generator and I need to insert in a few locations; the import section, fields, and at the end. It seems relatively easy to do using  with / combinations and echoing to a file at the end, but the problem is in the field section as I can't guarantee it'll be the same number of lines before the Class declaration each time (if at any point anyone adds anything to the code that's generated the comment section the code generator spits out will be longer) and I don't want to risk inserting my field in the middle of something (any field could have annotations), so basically I'd like to match one of the fields that I know will always be there, find out what line that is on and insert after that.

So in short, is there any way I can use ant to find the line number matching a regular expression or string literal? (There will only be one if that makes things easier). Oh and the solution has to be cross-platform compatible as there are others accessing the code on Windows/Linux/Mac.

Comment: So you want to do this with standard ant? No external libraries installed? e.g. ant-contrib?

Comment: There are a few external libraries available, but I can't add more, nor am I really sure how to find a list of which ones are available, so the less dependencies the better. Ant-contrib is one of the available libraries I believe (there's an ant-contrib-1.0b2.jar in our lib directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scripting (see [scriptdef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) usage) language `groovy` for example, or [`groovy`](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/The+groovy+Ant+Task) task to solve your problem.
I've prepared sample using `groovy` script:

```
<target name="checkfile">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="libs"/>

    <fileset id="files_to_search" dir="${folder.to.search}" includes="**/*.*"/>

    <groovy>
        ant.echo "Search for '${properties.str_to_find}' string"
        project.references.files_to_search.each { fileResource ->
          def file = new File(fileResource.toString())
          def lines = 0
          file.eachLine{
            line ->   
            lines++;
            if (line =~ /^${properties['str_to_find']}$/) println "Matches, line no: " + lines + ", file name: " + file;
          }
        }
    </groovy>
</target>
```

My output:

> checkfile: 
>   Search for 'ddd' string  
>   Matches, line no: 5, file name: d:\55\ouuu.txt

PS: I'm not groovy programmer, but this sample is working

Comment: This requires java 1.6 or later though.

Comment: Java 1.6 isn't a problem for me, the dependency on Groovy is a bit inconvenient however as it means I can't test it yet. I can't add 3rd party dependencies, but at least it should be doable once I can get someone to do that.

Comment: @Thor84no You can use whatever bsf language you want e.g. Java, Javascript etc.

Answer (score 0):

sed can print line number easily. (by using "=")

e.g. `sed -n '/yourPattern/=' yourfile`

will print all all line numbers, that the lines match yourPattern.

```
sed - n '/yourPattern/{=;q}' yourFile
```

will print the line number of the 1st match line

do know if this is what you need.

AND, sed is platform independent. :D

Comment: What is `sed`? Is it utility?

Comment: @AlexK Sed is a stream editor available on *nix. Unfortunately that makes this solution limited to *nix or Windows with cygwin or something to mimmick the *nix shell and sed installed.

Comment: Sed can be installed on windows sure, but try persuading entire departments in a business that all windows users must install cygwin and sed just to be able to build a single project. I'm afraid that just won't happen, I need something in ANT/JDK. :\